# Automatically running AnyLogic sliders so that different combinations are chosen

Tags: java, slider, combinations, anylogic

I am creating a system dynamics model in AnyLogic to be representative of a water mass balance for a city. One of the important aspects of this is to understand how different conservation measures affect supply-demand relationships. There are 3 different conservation measures and there are five different levels of adoption for each: 0%, 25%, 50%, 75%, and 100%. This makes a total of 125 combinations. I was thinking of linking the 3 parameters to sliders in order to choose the level of adoption, but going through each combination manually appears to be unnecessarily grueling. Does anyone know if it is possible that during run time the model is able to choose the different combinations on its own? If so, how can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameter variation experiment should be ideal for what you need: https://anylogic.help/anylogic/experiments/parameter-variation.html#parameter-variation-experiment

Create a parameter in main for each measure you want to vary. Then, in the experiment's properties, you can specify the range and step to define the different values you want the parameters to take.

Then, when you run it, all possible combinations will be run.

Comment: Thank you! I was not aware of this feature. Very helpful! One of the model's outputs is a deficit point (i.e. a time plot of demand and supply to show when demand surpasses supply). Would this feature give all the deficit time plots that are created with each of the 125 combinations? Or would it override each plot as a new combination is run? Thanks again for your help!